# Restarting a Gaussian partially constrained relaxed surface scan using GICs

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I am Using Gaussian 16 rev D.01, and I want to perform relaxed surface scans where I vary a bond distance. At the same time I constrain seven atom coordinates during the entire optimization (this is an enzyme active site cluster model).

Setting up the initial input is not difficult. However, as most Gaussian users would know, the optimization is likely to fail at some point due to the "Curvilinear step not converged" error. That means restarting the optimization.

The question then becomes **how to properly restart the relaxed surface scan automatically from the last point in the scan while at the same time not losing my constraints.** The Gaussian manual says that

```
geom=(CheckPoint, NewDefinition)
```

should not be used, and that instead

```
geom=(CheckPoint, GIC)
```

should be used.

My attempted input looks like this

```
%chk=mycheckpointfile.chk
# P opt=(tight)
# pbepbe/def2svp
# scf=(MaxCycle=1000)
# int=UltraFine
# EmpiricalDispersion=GD3
# geom=(CheckPoint, GIC)
# NoSymm

Relaxed surface scan searching for transition state

-1 1

Atom 30 Frozen
Atom 21 Frozen
Atom 1 Frozen
Atom 19 Frozen
Atom 56 Frozen
Atom 39 Frozen
Atom 55 Frozen
rSC(NSteps=15, StepSize=0.05) = Bond(15,59)
```

but this resulted in loss of my constraints. Should I add "AddGIC" as well? What is the easiest way to restart such an optimization?

Also, if this is easier with the old "ModRedundant" keyword then such an answer is also appreciated.

Comment: I assume you use revision B not D as that is the latest out there. Could you also post the input that fails. I think you need the addGIC option to specify for Gaussian to read the extra input. GIC does only specify to run the new algorithm. Otherwise I don't see any issue. How do you know you lose the constraints? Does it simply optimise? Can you find on the input of it read and GIC?